# PHP / SQL - Escaping characters in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, syntax

I have the following code on 1 page that works perfectly fine:

```
 $log = "UPDATE users SET loggedIn = '1' WHERE username= '$username' ";
```

However, upon changing that code slightly, something is going wrong escaping my characters.

```
$log = "UPDATE users SET loggedIn = '0' WHERE username= '$_SESSION["username"]' ";
```

The issue lies within my syntax here: **'$_SESSION["username"]'**

Unfortunately, the $username variable is not declared in this page. 
HOWEVER, $_SESSION['username'] is declared, and an echo of it returns exactly what I need.

I've been trying different variations of single quotes, double quotes, and backslashes for hours. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? ..

#### Solved by Enstage

Comment: Avoid the problem entirely, and avoid SQL injection, by using prepared statements with query parameters.

Comment: Do what David said, but just for reference, your issue is because of the quotes, change your query to: `"UPDATE users SET loggedIn = '0' WHERE username= '". $_SESSION["username"]."' "`

Comment: There is no possibility for SQL injection here as the user is not actually inputting any data, rather just clicking a logout button and logging out (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I forgot the append periods. Wow. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried this. The code seems to now pass, however there is something else going on that is returning failed. Updating the question

Comment: Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1